# Entity Framework gives me the old data although i changed them

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a strange problem with the Entity Framework:

I have a SQL Server database on a Windows Server and I access it via my app through Entity Framework.

Now I changed an entry in the database, but the app which uses Entity Framework still gives me the old value although its not saved in any place.

What could this be and how to fix this?

**EDIT**:
I'm getting the data from the database like this:

```
(from p in _myEF.master_Items where p.id == userId 
 select p.Location).FirstOrDefault();
```

**EDIT2**:
when I start it locally via Visual Studio I see the new value. If I use the deployed version, I see the old value which is not in the DB anymore

**EDIT3**:
here is my connection string `<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyData.csdl|res://*/MyData.ssdl|res://*/MyData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=foo;initial catalog=MyDb;persist security info=True;user id=Admin;password=xxxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: Not much to go on here. Is the correct value saved in the database to begin with? What type is _myEF? Is there more than one matching item in the table that you're missing because of FirstOrDefault?

Comment: Its all right, when I start it locally via visual studio I see the new value. If I use the deployed version, I see the old value which is not in the DB anymore

Comment: _myEF is of type ObjectContext

Comment: Can you please **show us** the connection string of your database?

Comment: <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyData.csdl|res://*/MyData.ssdl|res://*/MyData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=foo;initial catalog=MyDb;persist security info=True;user id=Admin;password=xxxx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Remember that EF internally caches items in the context. Is `_myEF` a new object for every request? Because if it's in a `static` field that's what's causing this.

Comment: its static, so this is the source of the bug, i will try to fix it and then tell if this helped. please post this as a answer and i will accept it

Comment: try to update your model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework caches objects internally in a `DbContext` instance. Those are meant to be short-lived, the purpose of the caching is so that every time you look up an entity with the same ID you get the same actual instance of said entity back.

This means that when using Entity Framework, you shouldn't store a `DbContext` in a `static` field. Create a new one for every request.