# Entity Framework Still Cache Although Use "Using"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to use Entity Framework for work with database, I use Extension Method and pass Entity Context Into Logic Codes, The Database is update successful, but when I call back, result, I still old Records, I guess that issue on Cache of Entities, But It not make clear, I could not find any thing wrong in my code. Please help:

Extension method:

```
public static bool UpdateTruck(this Truck Truck, Truck updateInfo, Entities entities)
{
    var isSuccess = true;

    try
    {
        // Find Enity Object
        var ObjectModel = entities.Truck.Where(x => x.Code == Truck.Code && x.CodePlant == Truck.CodePlant).FirstOrDefault();

        // Mapping Modified Properties
        ObjectModel = Mapper.Map(updateInfo, ObjectModel);

        // Create Database Entity Transaction
        entities.Truck.AddOrUpdate(ObjectModel);

        //Save Changes
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("[Application Exception:] " + exception.Message);
        isSuccess = false;
    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

- Here is where I call: `if (truckInfo.FindTruck(entities).UpdateTruck(truckInfo,entities))`

After that, i checked database, i value update success update, but when I call:

```
using (Entities entities = new Entities())
        {
            PageModel.Truck= Truck.FindTruck(entities);
```

....

It receive old record.

Comment: what is `Truck.FindTruck`? To query the database, you have to use the `DbContext`, which looks like from sample to be the `entities` variable.

Comment: Truck.FindTruck is a Extension Method Of DbContext, as you can see, the parameter of this methods is current context:

Comment: Well, technically it's not an extension method. If it was, you would do instead `entities.FindTruck`. But anyway what is the code of `FindTruck`? Post it here.. since without it it's hard to know why you're getting wrong data..

Comment: Here is it :`public static Truck FindTruck(this Truck truck, Entities entities)
        {
            return entities.Truck.Where(x => x.Code == truck.Code && x.CodePlant == truck.CodePlant).FirstOrDefault();
        }`

Comment: Try if this works for you, There is Quarable Extension AsNotracking(), find more details [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn237200(v=vs.113))

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework caches objects internally in a `DbContext` instance.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16567846/9320217)

Comment: I am create dbcontext instance each request, but seem not work

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't caching. You are using the AddOrUpdate method, which is only designed for use when initialising a database with seed data.

Use:

```
entities.Truck.Attach(Truck); // if it already exists.
// since you are loading it again for some reason
var ObjectModel = entities.Truck.Where(x => x.Code == Truck.Code && x.CodePlant == Truck.CodePlant).FirstOrDefault();
// Mapping Modified Properties
ObjectModel = Mapper.Map(updateInfo, ObjectModel); // this looks dubious
// You've just loaded it from the context so it's tracked, so you could just save it
entities.SaveChanges();
```